# Call the replacer *before* the object's toJSON?

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

Is there a way to get my replacer called *before* an object's own `toJSON` transforms it, so that I can work with the original object rather than its JSON-friendly form, *without* overriding the `toJSON` on the object or its prototype, pre-processing the object, or writing my own version of `JSON.stringify`?

For example: Suppose I want to serialize `Date` instances differently than their normal serialization ([which is `toISOString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.44)). (This question is **not** specific to `Date`, this is just an example.) The problem is, my replacer doesn't see the `Date` object, it sees a string (see snippet below) because `Date.prototype.toJSON` is called **before** my replacer.

```js
var obj = {
  d: new Date()
};
snippet.log(getType(obj.d));     // "[object Date]"

var json = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
  if (key === "d") {
    snippet.log(getType(value)); // "string" <== Want to see a Date here
  }
  return value;
});

function getType(value) {
  var to = typeof value;
  if (to === "object") {
    to = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
  }
  return to;
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to get the replacer called first? I don't want to override `Date.prototype.toJSON`, pre-process the object, or write my own `JSON.stringify`, but I'm not seeing another way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand you correct this should do the trick, I'm pretty sure `this` is always the object `JSON.stringify` is currently  iterating over:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
  if (key === "d") {
    snippet.log(getType(this[key]));
  }
  return value;
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. It even [works for the exceptional case](http://jsbin.com/zeciqiwawo/1) where you're stringifying a document fragment (`JSON.stringify(new Date())`), not a whole document, thanks to [steps 9-11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3).

Comment: Will it work with TypeScript 'this' if function is static/global?

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter):

> The object in which the key was found is provided as the replacer's `this` parameter.

So you can do this:

```js
var obj = {
  d: new Date()
};
console.log(getType(obj.d));     // "[object Date]"

var json = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
  if (key === "d") {
    console.log(getType(this[key]));
  }
  return value;
});

function getType(value) {
  var to = typeof value;
  if (to === "object") {
    to = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
  }
  return to;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there had to be a better way. :-)

Comment: Holy crap, this is an incredible hack. I always just assumed `replacer` was irrevocably broken, but turns out the fix was hidden in plain view all along!